# Firebase onDataChange() not being executed

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm rewriting my app. Wanted to get data from Firebase Realtime Database but the onDataChange() method looks as if its not executing.
I put in a couple of log statements to see what gets executed and all I get in Logcat are these:

> D/MainActivity: onStart()

> D/MainActivity: User is logged in!

> D/MainActivity: userReference reached

This is my model for user obejct:

```
data class User (
var client: String = "",
var email: String = "",
var isAdmin: Boolean = false,
var createJob: Boolean = false,
var viewJobs: Boolean = false
)
```

This is database data:

[image: Firebase Realtime Database]

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        userReference = database.getReference("users")
    }

override fun onStart() {
    bottom_navigation.selectedItemId = R.id.nav_home

    Log.d("MainActivity", "onStart()")
    if (!(mAuth.currentUser != null)) {
        val intent = Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java)
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
        startActivity(intent)
    } else {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "User is logged in!")

        val userListener = object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                //user = snapshot.value as User
                Log.d("MainActivity", "Client logged in!")
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                Log.d("MainActivity", error.message)
            }
        }
        Log.d("MainActivity", "userReference reached")

        userReference.child(mAuth.uid.toString()).addValueEventListener(userListener)
        this.userListener = userListener
    }

    super.onStart()
}
```

Full MainActivity.kt code available [here](https://pastebin.com/cmEh26Yu)!

Comment: Are you sure you have an internet connection on the device?

Comment: I would think i do since i need to first login in to get to this activity. Login is also handeled with Firebase.

Comment: `userReference` already pointing to the user location So why are you doing `userReference.child(mAuth.uid.toString())` again ? Shouldn't you be using `userReference.addValueEventListener(userListener)` only ?

Comment: userRefrence just points to /users in database but here i want to read one specific user data so I point to /users/(uid)

Comment: @ADM Just to be sure, i removed the child operator and still the same issiue. Also removed both so just reading /users

Comment: Do  not change it change the declaration only as `userReference = database.getReference("users")`  . also make sure `mAuth.uid.toString()` present on database .

Comment: So you say that `Log.d("MainActivity", "Client logged in!")` is never triggered?

Comment: @ADM changed it as you said, still same problem. Also updated question

Comment: @AlexMamo Correct.

Comment: @mike6715b What does `mAuth.uid.toString()` return? Have you also tried to use `mAuth.currentUser?.uid` instead of `mAuth.uid.toString()`?

Comment: @AlexMamo Both return "HNeWIg4ghRRC1ec2fYU7LkuBYL23" as expected.

Comment: Have you also tried to use `mAuth.currentUser?.uid` instead of `mAuth.uid.toString()`? Does it work that way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221875/discussion-between-mike6715b-and-alex-mamo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typo mistake or something in your ide.

```
userReference.child(mAuth.currentUser!!.uid).addValueEventListener(userListener)
```

Comment: Decided to start again from the ground up and this time it did work... No idea why but it did work.